# Incomplete answer

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

Just came across [an unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120074/repeating-section-headers-in-moderncv) for which I am close to finding an answer, but not yet 100%. Unfortunately, I am also stuck as to why my solution is buggy.

This let me to wonder what is the best to do in such a case:

- Provide an incomplete answer, hoping that someone else will improve it to be bug free / answer 100% of the OP's question, but unfortunately also decreasing the question's visibility by removing its "0 answer" status, or
- Do not post an answer, but post a new question with the (generalized) specific bug I encountered and returning with a complete answer if/when my own issue is solved, or
- Do not post anything, hoping someone else will solve the OP's question better than me?

Comment: I would say, post an answer *and* open a new question about the issue you're encountering with your solution.

Comment: and even make the posted answer as community wiki incase you wish so with a reference to `new question of unresolved bug` as Jake suggested.

Comment: I've been in the same situation and have gone with option 2: ask a question, learn something new, then come back and post a complete working answer to the original question.

Comment: Other option: We're not rep-hunters, so you can post it CW and some egreg or David Carlisle come, solve it and edit it directly ;)

Comment: I've had similar quandary when trying to answer a question to only discover there's a deeper difficulty.  How should the new question be posted?  There seems to be something awkward about posting a question that I might never have had except for trying to answer someone else's question.

Comment: If in doubt, post it.  I don't think that the visibility issue counts much.  And if you're really worried you can mention it in chat.  Posting a follow-up question will actually *increase* the visibility of the original question.  To A.Ellett's awkwardness I would say: don't feel awkward.  I've posted questions like that that I wouldn't have thought of by myself and never felt that I shouldn't do so.

Comment: In my opinion post a new question and add the link to the new question as a comment in the original one

Comment: @Jake: Perhaps you could write up an answer that includes your (and others') comments?